# how to push data in array object using php

Tags: php

> I expected this kind of data

```
 0 => array:3 [
   0 => "12"
    1 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
    2 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "10"
    1 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
    2 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
  ]
```

> but I always come up to this kind of data

```
array: [
  0 => "10"
  1 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
  2 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
  3 => "12"
  4 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
  5 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
]
```

> this is the code that I try, I just want to transfer the data on $data to $new_data, but it always give different result, and I don't know how to reconstruct my code

```
$data =[
  0 => array:3 [
    0 => "Employee ID"
    1 => "time_in (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)"
    2 => "time_out (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    0 => "10"
    1 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
    2 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    0 => "12"
    1 => "2017-03-28 05:29:56"
    2 => "2017-03-29 05:29:56"
  ]
  3 => false
]
$new_data=[];

for ($i=1; $i < $len-1; $i++) { 
     for ($x=0; $x < 3 ; $x++) {

      array_push($new_data,$data[$i][$x]);

     }
}
```

do please help me on my logic, I'm just new in array

Comment: could you post the contents of your `$data`? And I'm guessing `$new_data` is just an array;

Comment: You don't want to put your 3 `$data[$i][0]`, `$data[$i][1]`, `$data[$i][2]` values alone into your array. You want to put those 3 values into an array and then push that array into your results array. So put the values in your inner for loop into an array and then **after** the inner for loop you can then push that array into your result array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array `$new_data`, and you push six single new items. That's why you get one single array with six items.

If you change it to this, you get what you want:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $len - 1; $i++) { 
     $new_item = [];
     for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
         array_push($new_item, $data[$i][$x]);
     }
     array_push($new_data, $new_item);
}
```

This way, you push three items to a new array, and then push this array to your `$new_data`.

After I've seen your edit: You can also do this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $len - 1; $i++) { 
     array_push($new_data, $data[i]);
}
```

You don't need to iterate through the three single items if you always want to push the complete block.

Or, since you only want to seem to remove the first and last entry:

```
unset($data[0]);
array_splice($data, count($data) - 1, 1); // Remove last entry and rebuild indices.
```

Comment: I added two solutions that are more simple.